# Which Dedicated Server for FFMPEG?

Tags: linux, memory, server, processor

My website converts **video to audio and video to video** using FFMPEG (full Centos 64bit install). Mostly i got multiple conversions **(10-20) real time**. I use cache for already converted audios/videos. I am currently moving to a dedicated server and i need to know which configuration would be best for my situation.

Which of the below servers is better for FFMPEG;

**SINGLE** [Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1270 v5](https://ark.intel.com/products/88174/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1270-v5-8M-Cache-3_60-GHz), 8M Smart Cache, 3.60 GHz, 8 GT/s DMI3 (4 Cores-8 Threads) / 32GB DDR4 2133 / 240GB S3500 Intel Wolfsville SSD + 1TB Enterprise Grade HDD (for caching)

**DUAL** [Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2620](https://ark.intel.com/products/64594/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-15M-Cache-2_00-GHz-7_20-GTs-Intel-QPI), 15M Smart Cache, 2.00 GHz, 7.20 GT/s Intel® QPI (12 Cores-24 Threads) / 32GB DDR3 1333 / 120GB S3500 Intel Wolfsville SSD + 1TB Enterprise Grade HDD (for caching)

thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Does your software support GPU hardware acceleration?

Comment: I believe these servers has no GPU installed and no onboard graphics either. I am curious about more cpu cores will be more effective on FFMPEG or not.

Comment: Well with the second server you can have one core per conversion stream, but it is older.